Does the following GCD divisibility constraint imply that $\sigma(m^2)/p^k \mid m$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$?
The topic of odd perfect numbers likely needs no introduction.
In what follows, denote the classical sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$ by $$\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x).$$
Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$. (Note that we must have $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.)
Define $$G = \gcd(\sigma(p^k),\sigma(m^2)).$$
One can show that
$$G = \gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,\sigma(m^2)/p^k) = \frac{\left(\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,m)\right)^2}{ \sigma(p^k)/2}.$$
We then have
$$\frac{1}{G} = \frac{1}{\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,\sigma(m^2)/p^k)} = \frac{\sigma(p^k)/2}{\left(\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2, m)\right)^2}$$
Multiplying both sides by $\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,m)$, we obtain
$$\frac{\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2, m)}{G} = \frac{\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2, m)}{\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2, \sigma(m^2)/p^k)} = \frac{\sigma(p^k)/2}{\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2, m)}.$$
As the RHS is an integer (by definition of GCD), then we obtain the GCD divisibility constraint
$$\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,\sigma(m^2)/p^k) \mid \gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,m).$$

Here is my question:

Do we then have the implication
$$\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,\sigma(m^2)/p^k) \mid \gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,m) \implies \sigma(m^2)/p^k \mid m?$$

I only know that we have the reverse implication
$$\sigma(m^2)/p^k \mid m \implies \gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,\sigma(m^2)/p^k) \mid \gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,m).$$
In fact, I do know that we have
$$a \mid b \implies \gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(b,c).$$
Lastly, I know that
$$\sigma(m^2)/p^k \mid m \iff \sigma(m^2) \mid p^k m \iff m \mid \sigma(p^k)/2 \iff G = \sigma(m^2)/p^k.$$

Generally $,(a,b)\mid (a,m)\iff (a,b)\mid m,,$ which $,\Rightarrow b\mid m,$ when $,b\mid a\ \ $

Thank you very much for your time and attention, @BillDubuque! Therefore, I need to show that $\sigma(m^2)/p^k \mid \sigma(p^k)/2$.

Also, by your biconditional, I have
$$\gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,\sigma(m^2)/p^k) \mid \gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,m) \iff \gcd(\sigma(p^k)/2,\sigma(m^2)/p^k) \mid m.$$
By itself, this is interesting.
